# SSl Certificate on Port 8080 on ubuntu 20.04 with Apache2

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

i have a question, can i use SSL certificate on port 8080 with let's encrypt?? because i have Varnish on port 80 and apache2 on port 8080 and 443

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1333884/varnishd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1168629/systemd-res
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27647/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1837/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1333884/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      1079271/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1079271/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1335593/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1333884/varnishd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      27647/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1837/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1335593/apache2
```

and if i try to install ssl i get this error

```
Domain: my_domain
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://my_domain/.well-known/acme-challenge/wtWGU-02etvPPcCMHS_XbDZz6zC6uaFl5sMKwdcwdNw
   [ip_address]: 503
```

I'm pointing the domain with Record `A` and `AAAA`, it's almost 24hrs that I've pointed it

Comment: port number is irrelevant in context of certificate.

Comment: Unable to find a virtual host listening on port 80 which is currently needed for Certbot to prove to the CA that you control your domain. Please add a virtual host for port 80. 

if i point virtual host on port 8080 i get this error

Comment: Still - it is NOT about the certificate. It's about certification process of Let's encrypt (but this got absolutely nothing with the certificate itself - the certificate do not care what the process looks like). So by default certbot is validating domain ownership using port 80 but it seems that you can override this as well. See https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#certbot-commands -> http-01 challenge.